# Core Data setup advice

Tags: core-data

My app will consist of two categories, with sub categories then the items. What would be the best way to set this up with core data?  The main two categories as entities and the sub categories as relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is feasible:

```
Family        <----one-to-many---->> FamilyMember
FamilyMember  <----one-to-many---->> Item
```

Comment: Consider ticking the check-mark ;-) It's good for your approval rate.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to - must have hit it by mistake!